# AngularJS Json Editor

Tags: angularjs

Использую [angularjs](https://github.com/rodikh/angular-json-editor) версия для этого [json-editor](https://github.com/jdorn/json-editor).

Контроллер страницы:

```
var TaskEditCtrl = function($scope, $http, $routeParams, Notification, Task) {
    // Загружаем сам объект
    $scope.task = Task.get({id: $routeParams.taskId});
    // Загружаем схему
    $scope.schema = $http.get("/static/schema/schema.json");
};
```

Шаблон страницы:

```
<json-editor schema="schema" startval="task.data">
```

Данные в `Editor` не загружаются, открывается пустой редактор.

Как мне решить данную проблему (если это не ошибка в библитотеке)?

Comment: Пришлось искать решение на англоязычном сайте. Решение вопроса: [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33109159/angularjs-json-editor/33109535#33109535).

Answer (score 1):

Для решения проблемы Вам необходимо переписать код контроллера таким образом:

```
var TaskEditCtrl = function($scope, $http, $routeParams, Notification, Task) {
    // Загружаем сам объект
    $scope.task = Task.get({id: $routeParams.taskId});
    // Загружаем схему
    $http
      .get("/static/schema/schema.json")
      .then(function(res) {
        $scope.schema = res;
    });
};
```